# Rust chaining Results (Combinators)

Tags: rust, combinators

I've been following a Rust tutorial where two versions of a function are purported to generate the same results:

### Version 1:

```
pub fn get_transactions(fname:&str) -> Result<Vec<Transaction>,String> {
    let s = match std::fs::read_to_string(fname){
        Ok(v)=>v,
        Err(e)=> return Err(e.to_string()),
    };
    let t:Vec<Transaction> = match serde_json::from_str(&s) {
        Ok(v)=>v,
        Err(e)=> return Err(e.to_string()),
    };
    Ok(t)
}
```

### Version 2:

```
fn get_transactions_b(fname:&str) -> Result<Vec<Transaction>,String> {
    std::fs::read_to_string(fname)
    .map_err(|e| e.to_string())
    .and_then(|ld| serde_json::from_str(&ld) )
    .map_err(|e| e.to_string())
}
```

---

### However, I get the following message for version 2:

mismatched types

expected struct `std::string::String`, found struct `serde_json::error::Error`

note: expected enum `std::result::Result<_, std::string::String>`
found enum `std::result::Result<_, serde_json::error::Error>`

help: try using a variant of the expected enum: `_::_serde::export::Ok(serde_json::from_str(&ld))`,

---

which I been unable to make head or tail out of:

- Hovering over ld closure argument `|ld|` in VS Code it says it's of type `std::string::String`
- Hovering over the ld in the `from_str(&ld)` I get the message.
- Now I understand a `Result` is comprised of an `Ok` and an `Err`, but I thought the combinator chaining would have worked.
- The compiler suggested fix doesn't work either.

  - (or make sense): What is the `_::_` all about?
  - Why would the `Ok` not be inside the from_str?
- What would you have to do to make version 2 work?

Here's the [Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) with the methods for [combinators](https://learning-rust.github.io/docs/e6.combinators.html) in the Rust docs.

---

### Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
serde = "1.0.115"
serde_derive = "1.0.115"
serde_json = "1.0.57"
```

---

- cargo 1.45.1
- rustc 1.45.2

Comment: `Result`s need to have same `Error` type to combine them. For your problem you need to remove the first `map_err(|e| e.to_string())`, it changes the type of `Error` as a result you cannot `serde_json::from_str(&ld)` inside `and_then` because their `Error` type doesn't match.

Comment: The two commands 1) reading the file and 2) converting its content to JSON have their own individual errors. So will one map_err suffice?

Comment: Nope if error types are different you need to make it same then you should move the second `map_err` like this `and_then(|ld| serde_json::from_str(&ld).map_err(|e| e.to_string());` . With this way  both will have the same error type,

Comment: That doesn't work either.: expected struct `std::io::Error`, found struct `serde_json::error::Error` (I thought whole purpose of combinators was to be able to chain)

Comment: Nope for this case you shouldn't remove the first, just move the second one, please check: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b594ca16dfb6616519c78e2356f2403

Comment: Ah.. got you. That makes sense now. The error should be within.

Comment: @ÖmerErden If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it . Thanks.

Comment: It is ok, you can accept current answer if it also solves the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem comes from the `and_then` call.

You are not allowed to change the error type when calling `and_then`.
So your function there should return a `Result<Vec<Transaction>, String>`. However, the error type returned by `serde_json::from_str` is a `serde_json::error::Error`.

You can fix it like this:

```rust
std::fs::read_to_string(fname)
    .map_err(|e| e.to_string())
    .and_then(|ld| serde_json::from_str(&ld).map_err(|e| e.to_string()))
```

Notice the call to `map_err` is now inside the function passed to `and_then`.